# RethinkDb do function based secondary indexes update themselves dynamically?

Tags: indexing, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Let's say that I need to maintain an index on a table where multiple documents can relate do the same item_id (not primary key of course).

Can one secondary compound index based on the result of a function which of any item_id returns the most recent document based on a condition, update itself whenever a newer document gets inserted?

This table already holds 1.2 million documents in just 25 days, so it's a big-data case here as it will keep growing and must always keep the old records to build whatever pivots needed over the years.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand the question, but if you have a secondary index and insert a new document or change an old document, the document will be in the correct place in the index once the write completes.  So if you had a secondary index on a timestamp, you could write `r.table('items').orderBy(index: r.desc('timestamp')).limit(n)` to get the most recent `n` documents (and you could also subscribe to changes on that).

Comment: Or max(index=r.desc('timestamp'))

Comment: But here the max must be the max timestamp for each unique item_id (multiple docs with same item_id but must return always the most recent)

Comment: Ah, OK, so you want to write a query that returns the most recent row for *every* `item_id`?  If the number of `item_id`s is small enough that you can return them all at once, you could use `group` for that.  Otherwise I don't think that's easily accomplishable right now.